# How can I make this calculate the running total in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that lets me calculate  x(i)=1/i^2 for i=1,2,⋯,N

Here is my code so far:

```
end = int(input("How many times do you want to calculate it?: "))

x = 0.0

for i in range (0, end):
    x = x + (1 / end **2)
print ("The sum is", x)
```

I seem to have a problem with it adding the different values of X together.

How would I do it if i need it to work?

Comment: Do you mean `x = x + (1 / i**2)`?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using your increment `i`.

You are also dividing by zero.

Try:

```
end = int(input("How many times do you want to calculate it?: "))

x = 0.0

for i in range (1, end+1):
    x = x + (1 / (i**2))
print ("The sum is", x)
```

That should provide the result you are looking for. Enjoy!

Comment: For Python <3.0 this won't work as intended. You'd need to have a `float` in computing `x = x + (1 / (i**2))` i.e. `x = x + (1. / (i**2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Even in this little bit of code, there are a number of things to do better.

```
end = int(input("How many times do you want to calculate it?: "))
print(sum([1/i*2 for i in range(1, end+1)]))
```

Use built-in functions like `sum`.  They're a major strength of python.

Be careful with `range`.  Ranges start at 0 by default, and you don't want to divide by 0, of course.  Also, I take it that you want `end` to be the last value of `i`.  In that case, you have to add 1 to `end` to get it included in the range.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Accounting for divide by zero problems and using sum feature and list comprehension (more compact):

```
end = int(input("How many times do you want to calculate it?: "))
x = 0
x = sum([x + (1.0/(i**2)) for i in range(1, end+1)])
print ("The sum is", x)
```

Emphasis on 1.0 so you're not dividing by 0

Comment: Also in python, you don't need to say x= 0.0 to instantiate it, since it can change types and values.  So you ned to ensure as you iterate, you're adding correctly calculated values, instead of just 1 each time